# Como transformar uma data em formato objeto que contém dia mes ano e hora para somente dia mes ano

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, sum

De que forma da para converter data em formato objeto tendo dia, mês e o ano   hora, para somente com dia, mês e o ano para  realizer operações de soma de consumo de material por data?

Criei dessa forma mas algumas datas foram convertidas de forma errada;  dia invertido com o mês:

```
R3047['Machine types'] = R3047['Machine types'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
R3047['Machine types']=R3047['Machine types'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Ao realizar alteração de  dias acabam se invertendo com o mês.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é o uso do  [**pd.to_datetime**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime)  (notação importante de `to_datetime`)

> Deprecated since version 2.0.0: A strict version of this argument is
> now the default, passing it has no effect.

Essa nota afirma que *versão* **2.0.0** , qualquer conversões de data é mais específica.
E o argumento `format` pode ser omitido nas versões mais recentes do pandas.

E a omissão do `format` nesse caso ira inferir o formato  **string** data.

```
import pandas as pd

 
R3047['Machine types'] = pd.to_datetime(R3047['Machine types'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
 
R3047['Date'] = R3047['Machine types'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

 
R3047 = R3047.drop(columns=['Machine types'])

print(R3047)
```

---

```
R3047['Machine types'] = pd.to_datetime(R3047['Machine types'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')


R3047['Date'] = R3047['Machine types'].dt.date


R3047['Ano'] = R3047['Date'].dt.year
R3047['Mes'] = R3047['Date'].dt.month
R3047['Dia'] = R3047['Date'].dt.day


R3047 = R3047.drop(columns=['Machine types', 'Date'])

print(R3047['Ano'])
print(R3047['Mes'])
print(R3047['Dia'])
```

Os `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'` é usado pelo motivo se contem esses detalhes todos deveram ser convertidos ou pode ser omitido `%H:%M:%S`.

```
R3047['Machine types'] = pd.to_datetime(R3047['Machine types'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

E o uso do `drop` é para apagar o uso da coluna ou a linha, `Machine types` sera removido

```
R3047 = R3047.drop(columns=['Machine types', 'Date'])
```

Comment: Ao editar as perguntas não esqueça de verificar as tags. Após lido sinalize o comentário como desnecessário.

Comment: Muito obrigada, segui a recomendação e funcionou! :)